# How to use endpoint URL for API Gateway in client hosted at S3?

Tags: serverless-framework

I'm working on a serverless app that would involve SPA client hosted at S3, calling Lambda functions on the backend via API Gateway.

When I deploy my Lambda function with Servless, it prints out endpoint URL like: `https://ia6dga0can.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/stagename/fnname`. That is great, but how can I wire it together with my client code hosted at S3?

I am looking for a fully automated solution, ideally something that does not involve manually copying this URL anywhere or modifying the source in a way that would make it unusable with multiple stages (deployments).

Answer (score 2):

This is a complex question that would require some knowledge of your app and architecture, but I will try to give you a high level answer on an approach that you can use as a starting point.

If you want this to be a fully automated solution (which is the correct way to think about it) then you will need to add some form of build tools into your process. Some examples of these tools would be either [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) or [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/).

Here is a quick overview of what you might be able to do.

1. Start your build process with the stage as a parameter (test, prod)
2. Deploy one or more AWS Lambda functions using the given stage input parameter
3. For each of the deployed functions, use the [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) or read the output from the serverless deploy to get the URL for each gateway deployed
4. Use these gateway URLs as parameters to do variable replacement in your SPA config to replace the variables in the config with the actual URL(s)
5. Complete any other pre-processing on your SPA application (minification, hashing, etc)
6. Deploy the SPA codebase to S3

Answer (score 1):

I faced this exact same issue, and solved it by writing a custom plugin to build the frontend with the `serverless.yml` environment variables. The plugin is called [`serverless-build-client`](https://github.com/tgfischer/serverless-build-client) if you would like to use it. Then I used [`serverless-finch`](https://github.com/fernando-mc/serverless-finch) to upload the build to S3.

`serverless-build-client` is pretty simple; it just iterates over the environment variables, and adds them to `process.env`. This is the important bits

```
const environment = this.serverless.service.provider.environment;
if (!environment) {
  return;
}

Object.keys(environment).forEach(variable => {
  process.env[variable] = environment[variable];
});

// Later
spawnSync("yarn", ["build"]);
```

### Example

I have 2 separate serverless projects: one for the frontend, and one for the backend. When you deploy the backend, the stack outputs the `ServiceEndpoint`, which is the base endpoint that you will want to reference.

In the `serverless.yml` file, I have something similar to this:

```
plugins:
  - serverless-build-client
  - serverless-finch

provider:
  ...
  environment:
    REACT_APP_ENDPOINT: ${cf:<backend service name>.ServiceEndpoint}
```

Then in the frontend, I reference the environment variable to make requests

```
const response = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_ENDPOINT}/some/api`);
```

My deployment script executes commands in this order

```
// Backend
npx serverless deploy

// Frontend
npx serverless deploy
npx serverless build
npx serverless client deploy
```

Comment: I tried out the serverless-build-client - works great.....except when you are deploying to a clean environment. On first attempt at deploy it can't find the ${cf:<backend service name>.ServiceEndpoint} variable, so need to deploy it first and then put the line back in ?